# SQL query to return results from one to many table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having difficulties trying to return some data from a poorly structured one to many table.

I've been provided with a data export where everything from 'Section Codes' onwards (in cat_fullxPath) relates to a 'skillID' in my clients database.

The results previously returned on one line but I've used a split function to break these out (from the cat_fullXPath column). You can see the relevant 'skillID' from my clients DB in the far right column:

[image: skillIDs broken down]

From here, there are thousands of records that may have a mixture of these skillIDs (and many others, I've just provided this one example). I want to be able to find the records that match all 4 (or however many match from another example) skillIDs and **ONLY** those.

For example (I just happen to know this ID gives me the results I want):

```
SELECT
     id
     skillID
FROM table1
WHERE skillID IN ( 1004464, 1006543, 1004605, 1006740 )
AND id = 69580;
```

This returns me:

[image: Results]

> Note that these are the only columns in that table.

So this is an ID I'd want to return.

These are results I'd not want to return as one of the skillIDs are missing:

[image: Bad results]

I've created a temp table with a count of all the skills for each ID but I'm not sure if I'm going down the right path at this point

[image: Count]

I'm pretty sure that there's a simple solution to this, however I'm hitting my head against the wall. Hope someone can help!

**EDIT**

This might be a clearer example of when there are different groups of skillIds that I need to align. I've partitioned these off by cat_fullxpath to see if this makes things clearer:

In this screenshot, for example I want to find the ids for everything in table1 where skillID IN (1003914,1005354,1004701) then repeat for (1004659,1004492,1004493,1004701). etc

[image]

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: Again: What is your DBMS? Are you working with MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? PostgreSQL? ...

Comment: SQL Server @ThorstenKettner

Comment: Okay, I've tagged the request with `sqlserver` for you and added a promising alternative to my answer.

Comment: I’m pinging back out of curiosity just to see if you solved this :D

Answer (score 0):

We know that you need exactly 4 skills, so just make a subquery:

```sql
select id from 
(
     SELECT
       id
       count(skillID) countSkill
     FROM table1
     WHERE skillID IN ( 1004464, 1006543, 1004605, 1006740 )
     group by id;
)
where countSkill = 4;
```

Could work with `sum`, instead of `count`. But instead of filtering by the `4`, you filter by `4022352`, which is the sum of all `skillID`.

You can also remove the subquery and use `HAVING`. But you will obtain worse performance.

```sql
     SELECT
       id
       count(skillID) countSkill
     FROM table1
     WHERE skillID IN ( 1004464, 1006543, 1004605, 1006740 )
     group by id
     having count(skillID) = 4;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't help as for different ids they may have different skill Ids... Some may also have 3 skills or some may have 20 skills

Comment: You said "skillIDs and **ONLY** those". I assumed those 4 only, edit the question it's unclear...

Comment: @Brett: It's true that this would also report IDs having these four skills but also others. But you can't expect to get appropriate answers when you are not even telling us which DBMS you are asking this for. I asked that question in the request comments an hour ago and you haven't answered.

Comment: @Dorian: Funny that you are showing the highlighted "**ONLY** those", but this is exactly where your query fails. So, you've read it, noticed its importance, but still haven't considered this in your query :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner what do you mean, not considered? I considered only those 4.

Comment: @Dorian: They want IDs with these four skills and **ONLY** these four skills. You are not considering this. Your query returns IDs that have the four skills, but not necessarily **ONLY** these four.

Comment: @ThorstenKetter The `count = 4` will provide the **ONLY**. My query translates into this: "show me an id with any of those 4 skills. I don't accept anything else but 4". Which will result in ids with only those 4 and only with 4.  I still don't get it. But anyway, based on @Brett's comment we're clearly assuming stuff. I tried an answer based on what was provided.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - I was away for most the day yesterday due to a family emergency, so less of the 'hour ago' sass, please :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us your DBMS. Here is a standard SQL approach:

```
select id
from table1
group by id
having count(case when skillid = 1004464 then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when skillid = 1006543 then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when skillid = 1004605 then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when skillid = 1006740 then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when skillid not in (1004464, 1006543, 1004605, 1006740) then 1 end) = 0;
```

Another option is to concatenate all skills and see if the resulting skill list matches the desired skill list. In SQL Server the string aggregation function is `STRING_AGG`.

```
select id
from table1
group by id
having string_agg(skillid, ',') within group (order by skillid) in
(
  '1004464,1004605,1006543,1006740'
);
```

You can easily extend the `IN` clause with other combinations or even get the list from another table. Only make sure the skill IDs in the strings are sorted in order to make the strings comparable ('1004464,1004605,1006543,1006740' <> '1006740,1004464,1004605,1006543').

Comment: Hey @Thorsten, thank you for this. This helps me to an extent if I am putting in the skillIds manually. I have thousands of them so I will try and play around with joins to get the skillIds dynamic. From the query that you've provided here, this provides me correct results,  I just need to try and structure it so that I don't have to input the skillIDs if that makes sense?

Comment: And this is just a standard SQL database.

Comment: I've added an extra example to my original question. I apologise If I did not word it clearly.